# React onClick event trigger infinitely on render

Tags: reactjs

So i ran into some funny bug with React onClick event. So if I write something like this:

```
login = () => {
  this.setState({ authed: true })
  alert(this.state.authed)
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Loginpage />
      <button onClick={this.login}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
```

it would function normally but if onClick is changed to `onClick={this.login()}`, this event will be triggered on render and continue infinitely even after changing the code back and re-render this will still go on. I'm just curious why it ends up like that, does anyone knows?

Comment: show full code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you do this:

```
<button onClick={this.login}>test</button>
```

You are passing a reference to the function `login` on click of the button.

But if you do this:

```
<button onClick={this.login()}>test</button>
```

Then you are executing the function as soon as this element is rendered.

The `login` function triggers a state change:

```
login = () => {
  this.setState({ authed: true })
  alert(this.state.authed)
}
```

And since state change triggers another `render`, therefore it goes into the infinite loop.

Had you not called the `setState` in `login`, it would not go into the infinite loop.

Only your function will execute without even clicking the button on render.

Answer (score 4):

If you use this onClick={this.login()} you are calling the function as soon as it renders and not onClick, that's why your component is infinitelly rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<button onClick={()=>this.login}>test</button>
```

Comment: ```<button onClick={()=>this.login()}>test</button>```

Comment: <button onClick={()=>this.login()}>test</button> this will result the same behavior